# What is the right process in using Git Flow?

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch, branching-and-merging, git-flow

I am using Git Flow, "A successful Git branching model":
https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

but I do not fully understand it, so I am asking your help.

In our project we are using gitlab and there are 2 branches from the project which is the master and develop.

I was told to branch out from the develop branch so heres what I did:

1. First is that I clone the remote repository, the default branch is master
2. Second I branch off from develop branch using the command -   `git checkout -b develop origin/develop`
3. Now in my local I have two branches master and develop
4. I have a question when creating a feature branch, is it only locally?
   like using the command `git branch -b feature_branch`, is this process correct ?
5. Now if the above process is correct, and I have my changes on the feature branch should I merge it into the develop branch? is that right?
6. Now If I want to push my local changes, should I push it to the remote develop branch? or on the master branch?
7. If I pull changes from my team, should I pull it from the remote master branch? or in the remote develop branch?

Can anyone give a clarification to this, if you can give right commands, I'll appreciate that also, thank you. or a step by step process.

Comment: The only right way to use GitFlow is not to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your team's workflow, but it's usually safe to do the following:

1. Clone
2. `git switch develop`
3. `git switch -c feature_branch`
4. Commit stuff
5. `git push -u origin feature_branch`
6. Create a pull request into `develop` on Gitlab
7. Pull `develop` before starting a new feature

Comment: Basically in starting a new feature , I have to delete my feature_branch first head back to develop branch and then pull , and then create or start a new feature ? is that right ?

Comment: Yes, but I would only delete the feature branch after the pull request is merged. And use a different name for each feature branch even if you deleted the previous to avoid confusion and possible conflict with the remote branch.

Comment: In this case, I think it is not a must to always pull/rebase to the latest `develop` (although it is preferable and best practice). The reason is, by using this `feature-branch-<topic>` (branching out whenever you're working on a feature), it allows you or your other team to work in parallel. If there happened to be a conflict, it will just show up when you're creating a pull request (step no.6).